# SQL Server View combining/calculating data from 4 tables

Tags: sql-server, join, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to calculate the top cost of an invoice but in order to do this I need to combine data from 4 tables and sum it. I would prefer a solution with UDFs instead of expanding on the below view as it might become too big to manage.

The database looks as following:

The tables `Product` and `Accessory` contain the cost I need to sum:

```
(Product.Rentcost)    (Accessory.Rentcost)
```

The tables `RentedProduct` and `RentedAccessory` contain the invoice number I need to determine which invoice costs the most.

```
(RentedProduct.Rentcost)     (RentedAccessory.Rentcost)
```

So far I've only been able to get the results I want from Product using a join on `Product` and `RentedProduct` using this view:

```
CREATE VIEW Profit 
AS
    SELECT TOP 1 
        RentedProduct.InvoiceNr, 
        SUM(Product.Rentcost) AS Cost 
    FROM 
        RentedProduct
    JOIN 
        Product ON Product.ProductNr = RentedProduct.ProductNr
    GROUP BY 
        RentedProduct.InvoiceNr
    ORDER BY   
        Cost DESC
```

Comment: do you have sample data ? and please share sql for create table so that I can try write the query. Also please tell the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table-valued function as following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tvfn_TopInvoices(
    @Top INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

SELECT   TOP (@Top)
         InvoiceNr
        ,Cost
FROM (

    SELECT
             RentedProduct.InvoiceNr
            ,SUM(Product.Rentcost) AS Cost
    FROM RentedProduct
        JOIN Product
            ON Product.ProductNr=RentedProduct.ProductNr
    GROUP BY RentedProduct.InvoiceNr

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
             RentedAccessory.InvoiceNr
            ,SUM(Accessory.Rentcost) AS Cost
    FROM RentedAccessory
        JOIN Accessory
            ON Accessory.AccessoryNr=RentedAccessory.AccessoryNr
    GROUP BY RentedAccessory.InvoiceNr

) p
ORDER BY Cost DESC

GO
```

You can then use this function like this:

```
SELECT   InvoiceNr
        ,Cost
FROM dbo.tvfn_TopInvoices(1)
```